# Jenkins revert plugin

Tags: jenkins, transactions, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins project which executes `myProcess.exe`.

`myProcess.exe` takes `input.txt` as its input file and outputs `output00.txt`, `output01.txt`, `output02.txt`, ... `output99.txt` files.

I'd like to delete `output*.txt` files automatically when the build fails, and when the build is cancelled during the build process.

I mean I want the state of the project to be reverted back to the time before it builds.

Is there any plugin doing this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Workspace Cleanup Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin). It comes as an installed plugin when you install Jenkins.

You can set it up like below screenshot on the **Post-build Actions** in order to delete the files you want, when it is aborted or fails.

[image: Workspace Cleanup Plugin]

Comment: Note that I haven't tested the pattern for your .txt you want to delete. So maybe it needs to be differentiated a bit.